# Cron job can not access mysql

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, cron, vagrant

I got a big problem it spend me two days!

I use vagrant zendframework and mysql to make website, mysql is in vagrant box.

**Now I want to make a cron job, let it use zend function to access mysql.

> Tried max_allowed_packet, time out, does not work.

When I run cron below msg will come out:**

```
> Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in
> /project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php
> on line 129
> 
> Warning: PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet.
> PID=35388 in
> /project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php
> on line 129
> 
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
> 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away' in
> /project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129
> Stack trace:
> #0 /project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129):
> PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=ec...', 'root', '', Array)
> #1 /project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
> #2 /project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(861):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
> #3 /project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(931):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quote(42972, NULL)
> #4 /project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php
> on line 144
```

I googled a lot, the most answer is time out, but that is not correct for me. HELP!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try adding max_allowed_packet=64M to you my.cnf ?

Comment: Tried, I set it to 160M